# Increase the spacing between TreeViewItems in a TreeView

Tags: wpf, treeview

Im working with a TreeView in WPF.
What I have is :-

TreeRoot
-TreeViewItem1
-TreeViewItem2
-TreeViewItem3
-TreeViewItem4

What I want is

TreeRoot
-TreeViewItem1

-TreeViewItem2

-TreeViewItem3

-TreeViewItem4

So, Is there a way to increase the spacing between the TreeViewItems

Comment: Might want to edit your code, and put double spaces after each treeviewitem so they don't stack horizontally!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can modify the vertical spacing through the ItemContainerStyle property on the TreeView:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 20 5 5" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}">
        <TreeViewItem Header="One" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Two" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Three" />
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```